# strange vi behavior on OSX Debian ssh terminal

Tags: debian, ssh, osx, vi

While creating a swapfile I issue `vi /etc/fstab` as root.
fstab file comes up, great. Issue `G` `$` to jump to end of line and `i` to enter INSERT mode. Press the right arrow to move the cursor over by one character to the right. `vi` inserts a capital `C` on a newline. Confused, I press the left arrow key. `vi` inserts a capital `B`.

I'm pretty confused. Where do I even start to figure out what's happening here? I need to be able to edit files with `vi`.

Comment: Often arrow keys are translated into escape sequences. Those get interpreted as their constituent characters by `vi(1)`.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I guess I'll need to read the `vi` documentation more closely to figure out how to move the cursor to the left and right. (or maybe use `nano`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812973/linux-vi-arrow-keys-broken-in-insert-mode

Comment: None of those match the clues offered by OP: OSX, Debian and ssh.  Either OSX or Debian would provide vi==vim, and `TERM` is likely to be mis-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX "vi" appears to be vim.  Its version message says (for *El Capitan*):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2015 16:22:14)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

There is a remote chance that you are **not** using vim, but no one has offered a plausible alternative.

vim accepts cursor-key sequences within insert-mode.

However, one pitfall of this is if the actual terminal behavior does not match the terminal description set with the `TERM` environment variable.  For instance, the "linux" terminal description does not use *application mode*, and if you have set `TERM` to that while actually working in a terminal which has been initialized to use *application mode*, then vim will not expect a <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> sequence, since it is looking for <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.  The result is that you would get a `B` inserted when pressing the down-arrow key.

Further reading:

- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [2. Special special keys *ins-special-special*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special) (vim documentation)

Comment: This gave me the hint I needed - the `vi` I'm used to is actually OSX `vim`. When I installed and used `vim` on the Debian box, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vim which is improved,and can use the arrow keys,vi as default use keys `h j k l` to move the cursor
If vi is aliased to vim,check with

```
alias vi
```

So edit `$HOME/.vimrc`
and put in this line

```
set nocompatible
```

If interested on unix i usually use this vimrc

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
imap <esc>OH <esc>0i
cmap <esc>OH <home>
nmap <esc>OH 0
nmap <esc>OF $
imap <esc>OF <esc>$a
cmap <esc>OF <end>
```

Comment: I was wondering! `h j k l` are the way to move the cursor in `vi`. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys are being defined in your termcap(5) as escape sequences.  This is the default VT100 setting.  You can see the sequence in a terminal with: ^v followed by whatever.  Right arrow in VT100 parlance is ^[[C  (^[) is escape.  Notice this tells vi(1) to exit insert, move up a paragraph (none or one line in this case, apparently), and change to end of line. Similar unexpected results arise when using function keys in any program not designed to handle them.

There are 2 solutions to this type of problem which is neither OS, program, nor terminal specific.  The first solution is to use a vi(1) that knows how to deal with navigation while in insert mode. vim(1) is one such vi(1).  It works well w/ vt100 emulators and has its own GUI if you want to install it that way.  Many consider vim(1) bloatware, though; finding it slow and ponderous. Other probably more-bloated options include Eclipse(1) w/ vwrapper plugin, and emacs(1) with Viper plugin.

The other solution is to use vi(1) as it was intended to be used on real VT100s.  Do not use arrow or other multi-character function keys in insert mode.   The key sequence in the question:

G -- go to the last line of the file
$ -- go to the last character of the current line
i -- insert before current character

is incorrect for the task.  Instead of i use a -- append current character, so the arrow key isn't needed to get past the last character on the line.

OR, better yet

G -- last line
A -- append current line